# Debugging an injected thread

Tags: windows, debugging, reverse-engineering, code-injection, malware

I need to debug the code injected by a malware into internet explorer. By itself it wouldn't be problem if I could debug the main process, problem is I cannot run the malware from inside the debugger due to a lot of anti debugging measures (moreover the injection is not performed via CreateRemoteThread, nor via NtQueueApcThread, that by itself is already interesting and that's what I'd also like to figure out).

Is there a way to attach a debugger to the injected process? I can detect the thread I'm interested in using OllyDbg, but there's no way I can attach to the code to step it and understand what's going on.

Any suggestion from you?
Thanx in advance!

Comment: This most typically requires disassembling the malware code so you can find out how to disable its countermeasures.  Of course, it probably has a countermeasure for that as well.  Deleting it is quicker.

Comment: Aside from trying the obvious plugins for hiding Ollydbg, you could look into using a kernelmode debugger like WinDbg. Most anti-debugger code is meant to detect usermode debuggers, and I doubt the malware is loading some kind of driver just to detect kernelmode debuggers.

Comment: I can confirm that the malware is not using a driver, also removing the antidebug tricks is a bit troublesome due to multiple encryption layers and CRCs (plugins to hide olly have no effects in this case unfortunately). I'll have to try with WinDbg, it might work, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the anti-attach tricks are [listed here](http://waleedassar.blogspot.com/search/label/anti-attach). Some of them mention countermeasures too. FWIW, I was able to attach to the program mentioned in the first post (DbgUiRemoteBreakin overwrite trick) using IDA by enabling "Stop on debugging start" option.

If that doesn't help, I'd suggest posting to the [RE reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering) with more details.